# Log into a website from a Nodejs server using a POST request

Tags: node.js, post, web-scraping

I am trying to log into a website from my Nodejs server so that I can do some webscraping to gather user data but I am having trouble sending the POST request necessary to log in.  On the website it uses a form to receive the user's username and password but I do not know how to send a POST request that perfectly mimics the form.

I have been trying to use request to send the form
The first request is there because the form requires an id to be validated and I parse it out of the string so I can send it back in the form.

Whenever I send it it gives me an HTTP error 400 and a blank page that looks like this 
HTTP ERROR: 400
Problem accessing /pf4/cms2_site/view_deployment. Reason: NoEvent

This is the code I have been using to send the request from my Nodejs server.

```
        request.get('https://cdm.schoolloop.com/portal/login',{headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' }}, function(err, res, body){

            body = body.substring(body.indexOf('id="form_data_id" value="') + ('id="form_data_id" value="').length, body.length);
            var formDataId = body.substring(0, body.indexOf('"'));
            request.post({
                uri: 'https://cdm.schoolloop.com',
                host: 'https://cdm.schoolloop.com',
                path: '/portal/login?etarget=login_form',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                form: {
                    'login_name': "testUsername",
                    'password': "testPassword",
                    'event.login.x': 0,
                    'event.login.y': 0,
                    'redirect': 'pig4d2db88ad6',
                    'forward': '',
                    'login_form_reverse': '',
                    'form_data_id': formDataId,
                    'sort': '',
                    'reverse': '',
                    'login_form_sort': '',
                    'event_override': 'login',
                    'login_form_filter': '',
                    'login_form_letter': '',
                    'return_url': '',
                    'login_form_page_index': '',
                    'login_form_page_item_count': ''
                }
            }, function (err, firstResponse, body) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else if (body) {
                    console.log(body);
                }
            });

        });
```

If anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong in my POST request or how I could figure it out I would appreciate it tremendously.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could use the DevTool provided by the browser to look into the response of your request. For Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Comment: I have been using it, and used it to get to the code above, but I still do not really know what I am looking for.  Is there something that is specifically important I should look at?  Like cookies for example.  Are cookies important for form data processing?

Comment: Most backend would reply with some kind of error code :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors

Also depends on the backend, the error message varies, it would help if you attach ur http response in the question

Comment: I get an HTTP error 400 and a get back a blank page that says this HTTP ERROR: 400
Problem accessing /pf4/cms2_site/view_deployment. Reason:

    NoEvent

Comment: Unless the web pages you are trying to scrape are static you probably won't get very far. Most web pages today rely heavily on javascript. This approach will not run the javascript required to properly render the page. You probably want to use some kind of browser tooling to load the web page so you can scrape it after it has been rendered. Selenium is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger That sounds good!  I'll look into that.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You get the standard response for a POST to 'https://cdm.schoolloop.com'

"request" library identifies the resource throught uri, this should be the correct syntax for the post request:

```
request.post({
        uri: 'https://cdm.schoolloop.com/portal/login?etarget=login_form',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        form: {
            'login_name': "testUsername",
            'password': "testPassword",
            'event.login.x': 0,
            'event.login.y': 0,
            'redirect': 'pig4d2db88ad6',
            'forward': '',
            'login_form_reverse': '',
            'form_data_id': formDataId,
            'sort': '',
            'reverse': '',
            'login_form_sort': '',
            'event_override': 'login',
            'login_form_filter': '',
            'login_form_letter': '',
            'return_url': '',
            'login_form_page_index': '',
            'login_form_page_item_count': ''
        }
    }, function ...
```

Comment: Even using that fix I am getting the error page.  I don't think it has to do with the url.  Thank you so much for your help though

Comment: Wait, never mind. You are right it fixes that error, but now it just returns a blank page(which is not supposed to happen).  Thank you so much!

Comment: The blank page usually means a redirect, see the statusCode of the response. With the password in the example it's a 302 error that redirect to the login page